# Not able to get get data from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am trying to get the values of the component data that's wrapped inside the Book element of the TestHomePage.
For example, if the user types in the ID of a XML file, I am looping through the list of XML file contents in my local folder, and then trying to get the all the component data values that's inside that file in the Book element.

Here is what I have tried:

XML Data:

```
<TestHomePage ID="x123456" Name="Some Home page" IsComponent="false" Changed="....." Created="......" Layout="default.xsl" Published="....">
    <Book Type="List" Name="BottomSections" UID="......." label="Bottom Section Test" readonly="false" hidden="false" required="false" indexable="false" Enclosed="false" AllowEnclosureChange="false" CIID="" ItemName="BottomSection" ItemLabel="" ItemType="Component">
        <Book Type="Component" Name="BottomSection" Component="x1255655456" UID="caiiid19c71477" label="Bottom Sections" readonly="false" hidden="false" required="false" indexable="false" AutoEmbed="false"  Embedded="false"/>
        <Book Type="Component" Name="BottomSection" Component="x1233245454" UID="bhfejgbfjgfbh0" label="Bottom Sections" readonly="="false" WrappedUp="false"  Embedded="false"/>
="x12632454248" UID="5dgfdhg916fe12d0dcb" label="Bottom Section Control" readonly="false" hidden="true" required="true" indexable="false" CompTypes="SectionControl" AutoEmbed="false" WrappedUp=""Embedded="false"/>
</TestHomePage>
```

Python Code:

`

```
For example, if the user types in "x123456"
The values I am expecting to get back are x1255655456, x12632454248 and x1233245454. 

What can I do to fix the code?
```

Comment: `locations = xml.findall('.//*[@Component="' + COMPONENT + '"]')` will find all elements where attribute `Component` is equal to `COMPONENT`. So if `COMPONENT=='x123456'` you won't get any result in the provided example. I guess you want to filter `TestHomePage` by `ID`. It's not clear however if your file names already contain said ID...

Comment: Why did you remove the Python code from the question?

Comment: This xml snippet is not well- formed, could you please add the missing content? = should be < ? ? ?

Answer (score 0):

First I see your indentation is maybe wrong:

```
        for i in locations.iter('Book'):
    print(i.attrib['Component'])
```

It have to be like this:

```
 for i in locations.iter('Book'):
     print(i.attrib['Component'])
```

And then filter with the "ID" from TestHomePage

Answer (score 0):

Here is a draft version that seems to work.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime
import os
import csv

# COMPONENT To Search for**
COMPONENT = "x123456"

# Content Folder
TARGET = os.getcwd()

def theContent(file):
    return file.startswith("x") and file.endswith(".xml")

def handlingXML():

    for file in os.listdir(TARGET):
        if theContent(file):
            xml = ET.parse(TARGET + "/" + file).getroot()

            if (xml.get('ID')) == COMPONENT:
                locations = xml.findall('.//Book[@Type="Component"]')

                for component_elem in locations:
                    for attr_key, attr_value in component_elem.attrib.items():
                        if attr_key == "Component":
                            print(attr_value)


handlingXML()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob()` to list all files and check with `xml.entree.ElementTree` if your search have success:

```
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

search = input("What file content will you list, e.g x123456 ?")

dir_path = r'*.xml'
for file in glob.glob(dir_path, recursive=True):
    
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        
        if search != root.get('ID'):
            print(f"{file} does not match")
            
        if search == root.get('ID'):
            print(f"Your search match in {file}",root.get('ID'))
            
            Component_list = root.findall('.//Book[@Component]')
            for com in Component_list:
                print(com.get('Component'))
                  
                
    except:
            print(f"{file :>20} file can't parse!")
```

Output:

```
What file content will you list, e.g x123456 ?x123456
Your search match in x123456.xml x123456
x1255655456
x1233245454
x12632454248
pop_del.xml does not match
out.xml does not match
     xmlTest.xml.xml file can't parse!
a.o.
```

I used this well-formed xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestHomePage ID="x123456" Name="Some Home page" IsComponent="false" Changed="xxx" Created="xxx" Layout="default.xsl" Published="xxx">
    <Book Type="List" Name="BottomSections" UID="xxx" label="Bottom Section Test" readonly="false" hidden="false" required="false" indexable="false" Enclosed="false" AllowEnclosureChange="false" CIID="xxx" ItemName="BottomSection" ItemLabel="xxx" ItemType="Component"/>
        <Book Type="Component" Name="BottomSection" Component="x1255655456" UID="caiiid19c71477" label="Bottom Sections" readonly="false" hidden="false" required="false" indexable="false" AutoEmbed="false"  Embedded="false"/>
<Book Type="Component" Name="BottomSection" Component="x1233245454" UID="bhfejgbfjgfbh0" label="Bottom Sections" readonly="false" WrappedUp="false"  Embedded="false"/>
<Book Type="Component" Name="BottomSection" Component="x12632454248" UID="5dgfdhg916fe12d0dcb" label="Bottom Section Control" readonly="false" hidden="true" required="true" indexable="false" CompTypes="SectionControl" AutoEmbed="false" WrappedUp= "false" Embedded="false"/>
</TestHomePage>
```